# Framework 7 - How to set content on page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-framework-7

I have to set a chart on a page.

```
 Initialize your app
var myApp = new Framework7();

// Export selectors engine
var $$ = Dom7;

// Add view
var mainView = myApp.addView('.view-main', {
    // Because we use fixed-through navbar we can enable dynamic navbar
    dynamicNavbar: true
});

myApp.onPageBeforeInit('item0', function(page){
   // create chart code...
});
```

If i open the page the first time, the chart is on the page.
I switch to an other page (via the nav-bar in my app and I stay on my app) and than back.
Now the chart is never on the page.

One think is wondering me too; Framework7 creates per click ( changing the page ) new HTML-Tags.
[image]

Does anyone know why the chart is not added to the page? and why Framework7 creats so mutch new HTML-Tags??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to the mainView object:

```
preloadPreviousPage: true
```

Comment: how do you load the chart in the first time?

Comment: if you want to create it every time you get back to the page, so set preloadPreviousPage: false.
and change "onPageBeforeInit" to  "onPageInit", this way every back button will load the chart again

Comment: I create the chart with [anyChart](http://www.anychart.com/products/anychart/gallery/Line_Charts/Spline_Chart.php). I've got the js code form  the Webpage and paste it for a test into the `callback` function in  my `myApp.onPageBeforeInit(...)` method.

Comment: `preloadPreviousPage: false `   does not helps.